# meaning of "const char **p" in c

Tags: c, constants

If I henceforth first allocate memory for, say 10 character pointers, and then allocate memory for each of these character pointers to point to, then is p supposed to make the 10 character pointers read-only or is it supposed to make the strings themselves read-only?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const char **p` declares a pointer to pointer to `const char`.

> ```
> cdecl> declare p as pointer to pointer to const char  
> const char **p
> ```

Therefore, modify a character `p[i][j]` is incorrect, whereas modify a pointer `p[i]` is correct.

> #### C11 (n1570), §  6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, **does not have a const-qualified type**, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-
>   qualified type.

And, to use operators such as `=` or `++`, the operand has to be a modifiable lvalue.

Moreover, a code like this:

```
char **q = (char **)p;
q[i][j] = c;
```

leads to an undefined behavior:

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.7.3 Type qualifiers
>
> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
>   const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified
>   type, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Won't an improper attempt to modify a const value result in a compiler diagnostic before it invokes UB?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I hope it looks clearer now.

Comment: typo **modify a character p[i][j] is correct**?

Comment: does it make any difference if I instead say `typedef char *chptr; const chptr *p;` ?

Comment: @aditya: In that case, `p` is a `const` pointer to `char *`. So, yes, there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` is bound to the `char`, so it means you have 10 pointers to strings whose characters cannot be modified (via these pointers, anyway!).

Answer (score 0):

in this case p is a pointer to a pointer to a const char. Maybe an easier way to write it would be

```
 char const **p
```

(this code is equivalent to what you wrote). If you read it right to left you will see what p represents.

In this case, the char being pointed to cannot be modified using *p. However, you can change what p or *p point to.